# Deploying gcloud function from the console won't find code in zip file

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have a Python Google Cloud Function which deployment has 3 files.

```
root/
|_ main.py
|_ lib.zip
|_ requirements.txt
```

The lib.zip has some internally developed packages/modules, distributed internally bu another team. The requirements.txt has public libraries, like pandas, numpy, etc...

The main.py imports modules from the zip file by:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib.zip')
from def.xyz import xpto
```

Deployment works fine with gcloud-cli, but when I try to edit that environment variable and/or add other environment variables in the web console, deployment fails with the following error in main.py:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'def'
```

Apparently it can't find zip file when re-deploying from the console, although I see the file listed in the source tab.

The variables values are unknown to the dev team at deployment time, so they can't add them to the gcloud-cli command. And the operations team, who manages the web console, won't have access to the versioning repository, so they can't run the gcloud-cli command.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong or how to overcome this situation?

Comment: It should (!) be possible for your operations team to use `gcloud functions deploy` to update (!) the Cloud Functions and set the environment variables. I've not tried this but it should be possible to just mutate configuration.

Comment: For completeness, are you able to change environment variables on a simple deployment that does not include a zip archive? This will eliminate whether the issue is in generally editing deployments or specifically editing deployments that use zip archvies.

Comment: @DazWilkin Apparently your suggestion is a potential workaround. As a matter of fact, we got the same error when trying to configure a VCP Connector via the web console. But it worked as expected when we configured the VPC connector with gcloud-cli. Apparently there's indeed a bug with deploying via the web console.

Comment: @DazWilkin It indeed works!  `gcloud beta functions deploy <function_name> --update-env-vars=VAR=value` amended the configuration beautifully. My Ops team is super happy that they won't even need to go to the web console. Do you want to add it as an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: Great. Sure. It would be helpful to file a bug on Google's issue tracker for the Console-related issue: https://issuetracker.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Revising a comment as an answer with the confirmation that the approach works*

Your operations team can use `gcloud functions deploy` to update (!) the Cloud Functions and set|update environment variables **without** redeploying.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Adding my previous comment to this answer so others can benefit in the future: The suggestion in the answer can be implemented by simply:  `gcloud beta functions deploy <function_name> --update-env-vars=VAR=value`